# cURL try catch problem

Tags: curl, error-handling

I'm trying to debug this `cURL`-operation. The `var_dump()` is returning `bool(false)`

How can I make it exit the try in that case?

```php
function parse($url, $headonly = TRUE ){
    $agents = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16';
    try
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agents);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $curlResp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($curlResp); //RETURNS bool(false)
        die;

        $resp = str_replace("class=l","class='l'",$curlResp);
        return $resp;
    }
    catch( Exception $e)
    {
        $strResponse = "";
        $strErrorCode = $e->getCode();
        $strErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        print_r($arrCurlInfo, $strErrorCode, $strErrorMessage);
        die;
    }  //end catch
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try throwing an Exception when false is returned?

i.e.

```
if ($curlResp === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception(); 
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, what does false actually mean in this context? I'm new to cURL

Comment: Look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php; basically, false means the operation failed.

Comment: Saw that, just didn't see any methods to determine why it failed.

Comment: ok, how about this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php; this seems like what you're trying to do in the catch portion.